# Collecting all scss and build by Angular CLI or webpack - Angular 2+

Tags: angular, sass

When I do `ng serve` or `ng build`, I want the cli/webpack to collect all scss under the project and build it.

I have a component with scss like below

```
src/app/page/home.ts
src/app/page/home.scss
src/app/page/home.html
```

and I coded like below

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
```

As, you can see, I didn't add `stylesUrl` and I want to be compiled by CLI.

POINT of the Question: How can I let CLI compile scss files without adding them to @Component({styleUrls: ...}) or anywhere.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a new project, generate your Angular CLI project with:

```
ng new project_name --style=scss
```

Angular CLI will handle the rest.

If you already have the project:

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

Comment: Good evening, BogdanC.
Thank you for your answer BUT that's not the answer of my question.

Comment: Angular CLI is very opinionated about We pack, so either you use his way of doing the build or you do your own build and configure Webpack the way you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node-sass, sass-loader and raw-loader.

Install them and save to **package.json**:

```
npm install node-sass sass-loader raw-loader --save-dev
```

Then in you **webpack.common.js** in the "rules" section:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] 
}
```

And finally in the **component** you can use the styleUrls:

```
@Component({
  styleUrls: ['./filename.scss'],
})
```

Comment: Thank you alan,

But i do not understand your answer.

Maybe the question is unclear.

The point is: How can I compile scss without specifying scss files in styleUrls or anywhere.